# RLT 8822BE wireless problems

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

got some problems with the RTL 8822BE driver. I already have kernel 4.14 ( https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Realtek-RTL8822BE ). But there seems to be a problem:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

$ rfkill list all
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp5s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

$ sudo lshw -class network 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:e2:af:88
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.178.64 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f2304000-f2304fff memory:f2300000-f2303fff
  *-generic DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 00
       serial: e8:2a:44:ff:c0:03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=4.14.0-041400-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:139 ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f2100000-f210ffff
```

The method from toadjamb ([ubuntu 16.04 on hp envy ae000 wifi problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994150/ubuntu-16-04-on-hp-envy-ae000-wifi-problems/1002907#1002907)) gives me at a certain point:

```
 $ sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/build M=/home/multiple/rtlwifi-next modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:100: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8822be
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8822be not found.

I have securityboot swiched off in BIOS. Don't know what to to...
```

Anybody has an advice?

Greetings
 Lui

Answer (score 1):

> make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/build: No such file or
>   directory.  Stop

The missing 'build' directory often suggests that the linux headers package required to compile modules is not installed. Check:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-4.14.0-041400-generic
```

If you find, as we suspect, that the package is not installed, please download and install it. I assume you obtained the 4.14.0-041400-generic kernel image here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14/

Please select the .deb file appropriate to your architecture, either 32- or 64-bit, install it and try the rtl8822be compilation again.

Comment: Hey chili555, thanks for the soulution. It works now! I found out that i forgot to install 2 of the linux header packages. Sorry for that! thanks again! Lui

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour