# Still No wifi adapter for Realtek RTL8822BE found in 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

Just installed Ubuntu on new HP desktop "pavillion"all in one.
Dual boot set up. I get the message no wifi adapter found when attempting to get online.
What to do? Oh I do not know how to copy and paste my terminal info so it actually looks like it does on the terminal. (A little help with that would stop annoying people that are reading my questions.)

When I enter `sudo lshw -C network` I get:

```
*-network                 
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: enp1s0
version: 15
serial: c8:d9:d2:7b:00:b3
size: 1Gbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.0.0.223 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
resources: irq:49 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fea04000-fea04fff memory:fea00000-fea03fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe90ffff
```

So I followed the already answered question advice of making sure I had the correct kernel which is currently 4.15 and I have the most updated `rtl8822befw.bin` firmware installed and I still am getting the no wifi adapter prompt. I do not know all the commands that I could be using to get this solved. The adapter is found and operational in windows and the Ethernet cable allows me to get online for Ubuntu.

When I enter `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280` I get:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:831b]
    Kernel modules: r8822be
```

When I enter `rfkill list` I get:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any other Ideas ?

Comment: I'm assuming the adapter is found under Windows? And, for the time being at least, you can access the internet from Ubuntu using an ethernet cable?

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280` to your question to let us see what Wifi card it is. (If it's the Realtek RTL8821CE, as it is on other HP All In One's, then this is a possible dulpicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my pci wifi card rtl8822 working on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926364/how-to-make-my-pci-wifi-card-rtl8822-working-on-ubuntu) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004014/asus-rog-strix-z370-egaming-wireless-card-not-working

Comment: Hi Craig - I deleted some of my comments pointing to methods to download the driver for the **rtl8822be** - these are out of date as the driver is now in the Official Ubuntu Repositories. The driver should be there in 18.04 but something else is stopping it from working and letting you connect using your wifi card.

Comment: The output of `rfkill list` should suggest if something is being blocked by hardware or software.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/998182/344926)?

Comment: Can you please add the link to the 'answered question advice' you already followed in the question? *This will let us know what you have already tried*. There's a good wireless troubleshooting guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en and also a general wireless question with a script that gathers some useful information for wireless troubleshooting here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos (question is a few years old but the information is still relevant)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on a Lenovo Legion Y530 laptop, which has a Realtek rtl8822be wireless network card, with 18.10 Ubuntu MATE.

What I did to fix it was, plugging it into the network via Ethernet, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrage` then, using your favorite text editor, edit `blacklist.conf`.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I added the line:

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

then saved and closed the file, and rebooted.

If you didnt want to make this change, without testing it, you could do this:

```
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
```

Doing this gave me instant results. Wireless networks appeared, I was able to connect, and life was great again. I have no idea if your setup will have an IdeaPad module, but you might try it. Alternatively, you might have an HP module that needs blocking to enable this device.