# ubuntu 18.04 wifi problem

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless

After a reboot it **keeps asking for wifi password** and doesn't connect to any networks, **it can list networks**. After a few reboot it sometimes works but usually doesn't.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
```

```
uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic
```

It didn't managed to connect during installation either.
(it works in windows every time so its not a hardware issue)

It is a completely different problem I get a loop to type in the password and just can't connect to a network (I'v tryed the suggested fix anyway but didnt worked):

> [Still No wifi adapter for Realtek RTL8822BE found in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067286/still-no-wifi-adapter-for-realtek-rtl8822be-found-in-18-04)

Comment: I am 1 meter away from the router, as I said it works in windows 100% of the time, its some ubuntu thing not a problem with any hardware.
by unreliable i'm saying that sometimes I turn on my pc and it miraculously works so far this happened 3 times, and it works until I turn the pc off.

Comment: voting to reopen as the duplicate has a very bad answer

Comment: I have a similar problem: wifi stays connected for few seconds, then disconnects and asks for password

Comment: @NicolaG while the question was closed I re asked it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202109/ubuntu-18-04-wifi-problem-2nd-try there are a few solutions there, what helped me was: `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and `echo "blacklist rtwpci" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf` reboot