# wifi not showing on ubuntu 20;04 LTS

Tags: wireless, internet, laptop, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed alongside Windows 10 on Lenovo Flex laptop. The wifi works fine on Windows but when i switched to Ubuntu the wifi is not showing. I have tried many of the instructions on how to fix it but still the problem is not solved.

The output I get from lspci shows **Realtek RTL8822BE** wifi adapter present.

I really need my ubuntu wifi back, I have trying for 2 days to fix this problem. Thank you for the help!

Comment: What were you trying these ttwo days? Why don't you search for soulutions for `rtl8822be`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: A short search reveals:[an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067286/still-no-wifi-adapter-for-realtek-rtl8822be-found-in-18-04)

Comment: my  "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list" output this: 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
 Kernel modules: rtwpci
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series [8086:f1a8] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series [8086:390d]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: In Ubutnu 20.04, your device is driven by the built-in driver combination rtw88 and rtwpci. Let's load it and check the log for informative clues: `sudo modprobe rtwpci && dmesg | grep rtw` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555m, I get this output: [    2.866253] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    2.881741] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[    2.883654] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: mac power on failed
[    2.883658] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to power on mac
[    2.883660] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    2.883662] rtw_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    2.886021] rtw_pci: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -114

Comment: After some reading around. This solution solved my problem! Thank you all for the help.  https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Ideapad-320-touchpad-and-wireless-doesn-t-works-on-Ubuntu/m-p/3813154