# ASUS TUF FX705DU-AU035T wifi networks detected but can't connect, works fine on windows

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, wireless, realtek

I have ubuntu 18.04, in dual boot with windows 10. I installed ubuntu as soon as I got my computer, initially the wifi worked just fine, then some of the time (restarting several time would magically solve it), and now it just won't connect at all. It can see the wifi networks, but doesn't connect. The wifi works just fine on windows.
I have secure boot disabled.
At first I thought it might be a problem with the wifi adapter as it seems a lot of people had problems with realtek wifi adapters. Mine is RTL8822BE, however I have seen in one of the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994150/ubuntu-16-04-on-hp-envy-ae000-wifi-problems/1002907#1002907) that is supposed to work out of the box in 18.04... So I am at a bit of a loss as to what to do next.
Any suggestions?

Here is the output to the command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci, r8822be
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Here is the output to the command `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

<pre>04:00.0 Network controller [<font color="#EF2929"><b>0280</b></font>]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
 Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2950]
 Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
 Kernel modules: rtwpci, r8822be
</pre>